# How to use ServiceStack authentication correctly in ASP.Net MVC controller

Tags: c#, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I'm having problem with getting ServiceStack [Authentication] attribute to work in ASP.Net MVC4 controller, pages / action methods with the attribute keep redirecting Users to the login page even after the login details are submitted correctly.

I've followed the SocialBootstrapApi example, with the difference being that all the authentication web service calls are made from the controllers:

```
this.CreateRestClient().Post<RegistrationResponse>("/register", model);
```

Other things that I've done so far:

- Use my own user session implementation subclassing AuthUserSession (not too different from the example, but using my own implementation of User table)
- Inherit ServiceStackController on my BaseController, overriding the default login URL
- Enable Auth feature in AppHost with my user session implementation

Registration does work, user auth logic works (even though the session does not persist), and I can see the `ss-id` and `ss-pid` cookies in the request.

So my complete list of questions:

1. How do I make the [Authenticate] attribute work (or, what did I do wrong)?
2. How do I save and reuse the user session in an MVC controller? At the moment `this.UserSession` is always null.
3. How do I logout a user? `this.CreateRestClient().Get<AuthResponse>("/auth/logout");` does not seem to work.

---

**Update 1:**
The session cookies (`ss-id` and `ss-pid`) gets created when I attempt to load the secured page (ones with [Authenticate] attribute), before any credentials get submitted. Is this the expected behaviour?

**Update 2:**
I can see that the session is saved in `MemoryCacheClient`, however trying to retrieve it in the base controller via `this.Cache.Get<CustomUserSession>(SessionKey)` returns null (where SessionKey is like: `urn:iauthsession:1`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much fiddling around, apparently the way to hook ServiceStack authentication is to call the AuthService via:

```
try {
    authResponse = AuthService.Authenticate(new Auth{ UserName = model.UserName, Continue = returnUrl, Password = model.Password });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Cut for brevity...
}
```

and **NOT** `authResponse = this.CreateRestClient().Post<AuthResponse>("/auth/credentials", model);`!

Where `AuthService` is defined in the base controller as:

```
public AuthService AuthService
{
    get
    {
        var authService = ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.AppHostBase.Instance.Container.Resolve<AuthService>();
        authService.RequestContext = new HttpRequestContext(
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest(),
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse(),
            null);

        return authService;
    }
}
```

Everything else (incl. session) works correctly now.

Comment: What's the namespace for ToRequest ToResponse ?

Answer (score 4):

You can find how it could be done in the [ServiceStack Use Cases](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases) repository. The following example is based on MVC4 but works perfectly for MVC3 either: [CustomAuthenticationMvc](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc).