# Service Stack:Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'AuthResponse', got string starting with

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

i am using the following code to athenticate the user using ServiceStack basic auth provider in my asp.net application and receiving serilization exception.Please answer if anyone has solve this problem.Thank you.

I am using the following code in my asp.net application:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAuth" runat="server" OnClick="btnAuth_Click" Text="Authenticate"/>
```

I am recieving exception on **clien.Post method** in code behind file.

```
protected void btnAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                var baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/api";
                var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
                var authResponse = client.Post<AuthResponse>(new Auth { UserName = "admin", Password = "12345" });
                if (authResponse.ResponseStatus.ErrorCode == null)
                {
                   //Do Something here
                }
            }
            catch (WebServiceException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Followin is Exeception Detail which i am recieving on **clien.Post method**:

```
[SerializationException: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'AuthResponse', got string starting with:
```

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064166/how-to-use-servicestack-authentication-correctly-in-asp-net-mvc-controller  Hope that helps.

Comment: @DavidTansey, how is this related to the problem at hand? I am running into the same error and I do not even work with any web application. The problem is with the serialization of objects not about authentication.

Comment: How is this question related to MVC? Could you please correct the tags if it's not? Thank you

Comment: user2396029. it looks like the "Auth" class that you have written is not serializable.. try to make it serializable and try out, that should ideally work.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization exception that reads "expecting serialized type 'X', got string starting with:" means that the serializer tries to create an object from an empty string instead of a proper json-formatted string (*"{Class:{Property:{Sub:value}}}"*).

In this case, most likely cause is server at **baseUrl** returning no response (interpreted as empty string) to a POST request. Misconfigured URL or exception on server side, maybe?