# Check authorize in SignalR attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack, signalr, authorize

i have some services on ServiceStack and use SignalR in this project.

And now, i would like to secure hub connection (access only for authenticated users), but i use ServiceStack framework authentication.. (not asp.net authentication) and ServiceStack's sessions (write AuthUserId ih this session and authentication flag).

So, when user trying connect to the hub -- hub must to check authentication...

(yes, i can request Cookies from Hub (method OnConnected, for example), but SignalR check authentication in Authorize Attribute - and i must do it in this class (not in hub)

(http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization)

So, i create class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthorizeMyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool UserAuthorized(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user)
   {
     //... how can i request Cookies? / or may be can access for ServiceStack session...
     //    and return true or false
   }
}
```

What can i do for it?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't access 'user' from within ServiceStack?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know how i can do it. And 'user' -- this is Asp.Net (not ServiceStack) variable.. i would like to authorize user only in ServiceStack.. what do you think about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AuthorizeAttribute has two more virtual methods:

- `AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)`
- `AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

The default implementations of both methods call `UserAuthorized` with the request's `IPrincipal`.

`AuthorizeHubConnection` is passed an [`IRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.irequest%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) directly.

In `AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation`, you can access the `IRequest` object from the `IHubIncomingInvokerContext` like so: `hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request`.

Comment: so, can i get needed ServiceStack service for current http request context? (for example, using "ss-id" and "ss-pid" cookies) And check authorize for this session

Comment: for complete this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064166/how-to-use-servicestack-authentication-correctly-in-asp-net-mvc-controller -- and so, we can check user's session

Comment: `hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request` was what I was searching for - THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

I still struggled with this for some time trying to get the ServiceStack.Web.IRequest from the SignalR.IRequest so I could use ServiceStack's functions to request the session to see if the user had been auth'd. In the end I gave up and got the cookies from SignalR. I hope the following code snippet helps someone else nagivate this.

```
public class AuthorizeAttributeEx : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        return IsUserAuthorized(request);
    }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        return IsUserAuthorized(hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request);
    }

    protected bool IsUserAuthorized(IRequest thisRequest)
    {

        try
        {
            // Within the hub itself we can get the request directly from the context.
            //Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IRequest myRequest = this.Context.Request; // Unfortunately this is a signalR IRequest, not a ServiceStack IRequest, but we can still use it to get the cookies.

            bool perm = thisRequest.Cookies["ss-opt"].Value == "perm";
            string sessionID = perm ? thisRequest.Cookies["ss-pid"].Value : thisRequest.Cookies["ss-id"].Value;
            var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(sessionID);
            CustomUserSession session = HostContext.Cache.Get<CustomUserSession>(sessionKey);

            return session.IsAuthenticated; 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // probably not auth'd so no cookies, session etc.
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```